# How to install gdk-pixbuf-devel on Amazon Linux?

Tags: yum, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to install gdk-pixbuf-devel on Amazon Linux so I can use pixbuf with cairocffi in python.

I found an RPM located here: https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/12.2/x86_64/gdk-pixbuf-devel-2.26.1-2.1.4.x86_64.html

And I've been using yum to install all dependencies first so I can install this package. The problem comes when I get to the package libpng14-devel-1.4.11-2.5.1.x86_64, which requires pkg-config. When I try to install pkg-config, I get an error: pkg-config-0.28-7.1.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pkgconfig-1:0.27.1-2.7.amzn1.x86_64.

How do I resolve this issue? Or is there another way altogether to install gdk-pixbuf-devel?

Comment: You can't just mix and match RPMs from wrong Linux distributions.